# nVidia X Server settings - kernel error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, xorg

I was trying to install the nvidia drivers - first time, everything went fine.  I could access the nvidia-settings and switch graphic cards. But after a system update I now have lost access to nvidia-settings (throwing an error):

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

So I tried to:

1. Switch between driver versions & Nouveau
2. Manually install nVidia drivers from site and block Nouveau drivers
3. Remove everything and install again

For now I am at the point where I started, but I noticed that there is an error while trying to install nvidia-410 recommended drivers or dpkg-reconfigure them:

```
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-410.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/410.73/build/make.log for more information.
```

What should I do now to make nvidia-settings working - or - simply switch my gpu permanently to nvidia?

**UPDATE**

Weird, but downgrading to nvidia version 390 works fine. Any version above is still unavailable for install

**UPDATE 2**

I cannot place the make.log content as it was removed with the driver. For anyone trying to downgrade their drivers, 
[I followed these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050423/cannot-get-nvidia-graphics-card-to-work-on-ubuntu-18-04). Please note that in step eight I have chosen 390 nvidia drivers. Also, dpkg-reconfigure was used on nvidia-dkms and xservice-xorg but I can't tell if that was necessary. There is also a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1800348) on launchpad, but with another version of drivers I guess.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It appears that there is useful information available in the file `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/410.73/build/make.log` which could shed some light on the problem. grepping the log for errors would likely provide useful output that you could [edit] into your question. Your update on the other hand looks like the beginnings of an answer. A detailed answer on how you accomplished the downgrade would likely be useful to others who have the same issue.

Comment: okay , I will try to place the information from logs if there are any as I installed the driver successfully

Comment: If installing 390 resolved your problem, you should simply answer the question detailing how you downgraded to 390 for those with the same issue you originally had. I was simply trying to point out how your system was attempting to help you.

Comment: @ElderGeek I updated my question but I thought that it is not an answer - the problem still occurs in higher driver version so it is not resolved