# Black screen after login screen due to Nvidia driver

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce

Ubuntu 18.04, Nvidia driver 440. Most steps I've done from links:

[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely). Purge anything related to nvidia.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

2. Reinstall nvidia driver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

3. Steps from the [Nvidia forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1068626/linux/black-screen-after-install-of-nvidia-driver-ubuntu/)

```
sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-prime
sudo prime-select nvidia
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

4. Create `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` file

Including the following in the .conf file:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
options nouveau modeset=0`
```

5. Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Black screen after login.. So I did an insanity check in Recovery mode (root).

`nvidia-smi` and `lshw -c video` can be seen in this snapshot.

[image]

Everything looks good, but the issue still persists.

Following [Cannot get NVIDIA graphics card to work on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050423/cannot-get-nvidia-graphics-card-to-work-on-ubuntu-18-04), I disabled BIOS Secure boot and rebooted, but I was still unable to solve it.